# Angular 2 :put all form fields in json object when submitted

Tags: json, forms, angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-form

I have a form have multiple fields and I want to retrieve the data when submit it.

this is the component.html :

```
<div class="ui raised segment">
  <h2 class="ui header">Demo Form: Sku</h2>
  <form #f="ngForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)"
        class="ui form">

    <div class="field">
      <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="skuInput"
             placeholder="SKU"
             name="sku" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="select1" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">Langues:français/anglais: </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="note" id="select1" ngModel>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>

      <label for="select2" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">Langues:français/anglais: </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="note" id="select2" ngModel>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>

      <label for="select3" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">Langues:français/anglais: </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="note" id="select3" ngModel>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and here the component.ts :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-history',
  templateUrl: './post-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-history.component.css']
})
export class PostHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form: any): void {
    console.log('you submitted value:', form);
  }

}
```

in the console log it show me only the text input and only one select value !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `select` elements have the same `name` attribute of "note". You could change them to match the id's of the elements:

```
<select class="form-control" name="note1" id="select1" ngModel>

<select class="form-control" name="note2" id="select2" ngModel>

// etc
```